# How to display stored locations from a database on a map in android?

Tags: android, phpmyadmin, android-maps

I want to build an app which will display restaurants stored in a database (name, lat, long etc...) on a map within certain radius from the user. The user can then click on a particular restaurant to view more information or add a review about that restaurant. I know how to fetch the name of restaurants from the database using JSON and PHP and display them in a list view. But I want to be able to display them on a map. Could someone please point me in the correct direction on how to get this done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have a list of Restaurant objects that you can build from the data off your database:

```
private void addMarkers(List<Restaurant> restaurants){
    for(Restaurant res : restaurants){
        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
        options.position(new LatLng(res.getLatitude(), res.getLongitude()));
        options.title(res.getName());
        options.snippet(tagsnap.getAddress());
        getMap().addMarker(options);
    }
}
```

Call this with something like:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    ...
    List<Restaurant> restaurants = databaseHelper.fetchAllRecordsAsRestaurantList();
    addMarkers(restaurants);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the GPS co-ordinates of the restaurants you want to display. You can display the names but you need the co-ordinates to pass to a `MapView` so that it can display them as overlaid items on the map.

These tutorials will help you:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html

Comment: Thanks! I will try these guides.